# How to write my custom code for desiging any layout which automatically fixces the layout for iPhone 4 and iPhone 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6

I am not using any XIBs in my project. I am designing my views or any thing by custom code. It was good till iPhone 4. But with iPhone 5 I am getting a problem when I want to make the app compatible with iPhone 5. Its screen height is larger than previous iPhone. I want to make it automatically compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to you .m/.h files

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height == 568 )
```

This will return YES if the device is iPhone5 i.e 4 inch screen. Use it like:

```
if(IS_IPHONE_5) {
     //set frame of objects for 4 inch screen - iPhone 5 or new iPod Touch
}else {
     //set frame of objects for 3.5 inch screen - IPhone 4S or earlier devices
}
```

I'm using the same solutions in many of my apps. Hope this helps. :)

Comment: its helps but if we want to frame the in views'

Comment: if you want to frame the in views(i think you ment subviews) you can can use the autoresizing property of the view. Lets suppose you have a view "a" which contains an imageView "b". If you want the size of "b" to change according to "a" then use something like:-
b.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth

Comment: there are other properties also for having a relative control over "origin" property of the frame too. experimenting with them will give you greater understanding. Since the arrival of 4inch iPhone, this property has become very significant.